# What is adserver.video/sync doing in my error logs?

Tags: asp.net, http, logging, web, spam

In my web logs I see thousands of error messages like `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).` and the url in question is something like:

```
{valid site url}/https:/adserver.video/sync/03635d2e5423be5c297a9b6f812b727e/%3Faction=in&uid=5053622972360253088
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't coming from anything on my site. Is this an attack of some kind? Or could it be some badly behaved third party js library that I'm using incorrectly? There's nothing on the net about this, so does anyone recognize this url?